# Is there a method to implement mutex on Python 3.3?

Tags: mutex, python-3.3

I'm setting up an IPC method on python script and want to implement mutex synchronization method. How i can do to implement it ?
I found this library but it's deprecated since 2.6 :'( =>
https://docs.python.org/2/library/mutex.html 
I've some requirement :

1. I can't used external library (so, i can't used win32event for exemple or Pypi library)

   The mutex are created on an other process that is implement in C++, so it's mutex named.

   I'm forced to use Python 3.3.

There is an other way to implement mutex with default python 3.3 library ?
EDIT : The threading library can be use to do this ?

Comment: I will try to used this : http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577794-win32-named-mutex-class-for-system-wide-mutex/

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveState recipe doesn't work with python 3 strings (as these are unicode in python 3).

One fix is to change the declaration of _CreateMutex to the following:

```
_CreateMutex = ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateMutexW
_CreateMutex.argtypes = [wintypes.LPCVOID, wintypes.BOOL, wintypes.LPCWSTR]
_CreateMutex.restype = wintypes.HANDLE
```

Alternatively if the name contains only ascii values then encode it so you are passing bytes.

Comment: Python 3 strings are not UTF-16.

Comment: The implementation uses a 1-byte, 2-byte, or 4-byte fixed-width format, depending on the maximum code point included in the string.

Comment: I believe I am correct about Python in windows from experience with an early version of pyahocorasick which was developed in Linux where what you say is correct, but in Windows the C++ code was seeing UTF-16 encoding when the code point was above 65535.

Comment: If you were looking at a really old Python 3, you might have been looking at the old Py_UNICODE format, which was either UCS-4 or UCS-2 with limited UTF-16 support, depending on platform.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. It was happening in 3.5 (although it might have been 3.4).