# How to access windows mutex in python?

Tags: python, windows, mutex, python-multiprocessing, pywin32

I have a program `P1` (it was written in C# but that is essentially unimportant) that acquires a Win32 mutex. A second program `P2` that I need to write in python uses a shared resource with `P1`. Since this resource is already protected by the Win32 mutex I just need to access the same mutex from python `P2`. My questions now are:

1. I have not found any method to access existing windows mutex from the python multiprocessing package. Is there a way to do that?
2. Alternatively, it could be possible to use the win32event package. But since there is only a very [limited documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32event.html) with virtually no example code available, I am hesitant to further go in that direction. Do you know of any other resources on pywin32?
3. It would be nice not to introduce new dependencies. How ever, if there is no other way, do you have suggestions for (well maintained) python packages?

I am just baffled that I could not find other people with similar questions. This should be a fairly common problem, right?

Edit: My question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310049/proper-use-of-mutexes-in-python). As explained in the accepted answer, the multiprocessing.Lock method is only able to lock python processes. I however, need to aquire an existing Windows mutex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper use of mutexes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310049/proper-use-of-mutexes-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for looking into that. Unfortunately, it does not answer my question completely. The accepted answer is not using a Windows mutex - multiprocessing.Lock is only able to synchronise python processes.

Comment: @Isotope [use `ctypes` to import relevant Win32 API functions](https://github.com/benhoyt/namedmutex)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, that would be the perfect solution. But it seems that the repository is not very well maintained. Also, the short example provided in the ReadMe does not work anymore. I am receiving an `ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I found a solution to the commented problem above. It is best described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55922044/is-there-a-method-to-implement-mutex-on-python-3-3).

Comment: @Isotope Nice, does that solve your problem then?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, that solves my problem! If you write an answer I would be happy to accept it.